# Signature mismatch error in a complicated structure of modules and functors

Tags: recursion, types, module, ocaml, functor

I have built a complicated structure with modules, which has a recursion inside. The compilation gives me an error I can't solve (though I don't think it is really due to the recursion). Could anyone help?

First, an interface `ZONE` and a functor `ZoneFunPrec` are defined:

```
(* zone.ml *)
module type ZONE = sig
  type prop
  type info 
  type t
end

(* zoneFunPrec.ml *)
open Prop
open Zonesm
module ZoneFunPrec (Prop : PROP)(Prec: ZONESM with type prop = Prop.t) = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type info = { mark: int option; prec: Prec.t option }
  type t = { prop: prop; info: info }
end
```

A functor `ZonesFun` and an interface `ZONES` whose element is a list of zones with same property:

```
(* zones.ml *)
open Prop
open Zone
module type ZONES = sig
  type prop
  type zone
  type t  
end
module ZonesFun (Prop: PROP) (Zone: ZONE with type prop = Prop.t) = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type zone = Zone.t
  type t = | ZSbot | ZS of zone list
end
```

A functor `ZonesmFun` and an interface `ZONESM` whose element is a map from `String` into `ZONES` with same property:

```
(* zonesm.ml *)
open Prop
open Zone
open Zones
module SMap = Map.Make(String)
module type ZONESM = sig
  type prop
  type zones
  type t 
end
module ZonesmFun (Prop: PROP)
                 (Zone: ZONE with type prop = Prop.t)  
                 (Zones: ZONES with type zone = Zone.t) = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type zones = Zones.t
  type t = | Bot | ZSM of Zones.t SMap.t
end
```

And then, I try to build some modules from `EEA` whose interface is `PROP`:

```
(* modules.ml *)
open E_expression_abs
open Zone
open ZoneFunPrec
open Zones
open Zonesm
module EEA = E_expression_abs
module rec ZoneEEA : ZONE = ZoneFunPrec(EEA)(ZonesmEEA)
and ZonesEEA : ZONES = ZonesFun(EEA)(ZoneEEA)
and ZonesmEEA : ZONESM = ZonesmFun(EEA)(ZoneEEA)(ZonesEEA)
```

In my `makefile`, the order of compilation is same as the order I listed the files above. Then the compiler gives me an error in line `module rec...`:

```
File "domains/modules.ml", line 7, characters 45-54:
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
         sig
           type prop = ZonesmEEA.prop
           type zones = ZonesmEEA.zones
           type t = ZonesmEEA.t
         end
       is not included in
         sig type prop = EEA.t type zones type t end
           Type declarations do not match:
         type prop = ZonesmEEA.prop
       is not included in
         type prop = EEA.t
```

So apparently, the compiler doesn't manage to know `ZonesEEA.prop` is actually `EEA.t`...

Comment: These modules have inter-file mutual dependency. Are you sure that you  can compile zone*.ml files properly?

Comment: Yes, I just checked the output of `makefile`, their `.cmi` and `.cmx` are well compiled...

Comment: Ah, ok, the first code is for two files...

Comment: A self-contained file would be easier to reproduce ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at recursive module typing but... I guess your example is simplified to the following

```
module type S = sig type t end
module rec R : S = (R : S with type t = int)
```

OCaml rejects this code due to signature mismatch. This is since R has incompatible types in the left and right hands of the equation. You must say:

```
module rec R : S with type t = int = (R : S with type t = int)
```

R must have the same module type in the both hands, since R is defined recursively.

If not recursive you can say:

```
module M = struct type t = int end
module N : S = (M : S with type t = int)
```

The module type of the left hand side of the equation can be more abstract than the right one.